# After receiving bitcoin, they were sent to an unknown address 16 minutes later

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, mycelium-wallet

I received BTC payment from my friend by qr code scaning on date 31st July (1 day before 1st August HF).

https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/8710bdb6f1d34e882bab7fbbdb4b94266032672c54a042df88e25d1518ab40a8

The incoming transaction has shown on my wallet (Mycelium) as unconfirmed with another transaction says all BTC has sent out immediately to a address I never known before.

https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/176dfd5d7f28fafef60e071588bb464a6426382d8ef5315d57e5b5852c1e0e48) (as non standard transaction with version 2)

After I reload it says network error and the most of my transaction history disappeared from wallet till now.

This make all my BTC has stuck in address `1MDJk9xhPVyVH3RcXmhYBRL9bJrwgAbsN3` without move till date 4th November (nearly segwit2x) all BTC has sent to another address again.

This is huge amount of BTC for me, I tried so hard to find the answer what happen with my BTC but really has no idea. But I'm sure my wallet not compromised and my BTC still sit in that address without used.

I have 0.5 BTC and 0.5 BCH for reward if I can get it back. It's not so much but please help me...

I apologize for my poor English language skill, You can ask me for more information to understand clearly.

Comment: Sounds like your coins are gone! Are you the owner of 1ThothNC8w3mx4rGDtErxuTKegcUCX2ug ? I can see that your BTC immediately got sent away seconds after arriving your address. My guess is that either your computer/wallet is compromised or that vanity address is compromised.

Comment: What wallet are you using?

Comment: Mycelium both, There are many users have same issues, transaction history roll back or disappeared and lost BTC. My transaction history on Mycelium still show latest as 20th March and get error when I import this private key to bitcoin core.

Answer (score 1):

> **I tried so hard to find the answer what happen with my BTC but really has no idea.**

One possible explanation is that the BTC were stolen by someone who, at some time in the past, helped generate your private-keys and vanity-address or had access to your wallet and extracted your private keys or who otherwise compromised the security of your computer, perhaps using malware.